# How to get the length of "prüfen" in velocity

Tags: velocity

I was trying to get the length of "prüfen" in velocity.

Example:

```
#set ($data = "prüfen")

#set( $total_length = $data.length())

$total_length  // Output is 6
```

Question : I want output as 7 (as character "ü" occupies size of 2)
How to get the length of "prüfen" in velocity.

I have also tried with

```
#set( $len_of_data = $data.getBytes().length)

$len_of_data
```

But nothing is working.

Comment: No, How you are saying its 2 char? it will consider as a single only it doesn't know.

Comment: I don't know the better way but you could `replace ascii` using some utils and consider as a letter.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.
i want the byte count
Example:
character count is 6 in "prüfen" but byte count 7

Comment: byte count you are already getting as `7` Are you not getting the value?

Comment: No I am not getting the byte count as 7. I am only getting the string.length() as 6

Comment: In the above example: $total_length is printing as 6, but i want the output as 7
$data.getBytes().length is not working, is there any alternative method ?

Comment: I didn't find any alternatives . Velocity support only public method since length is not public it is not working .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
#set ($data = "prüfen")
#set( $total_length = $data.getBytes('UTF-8').size())
$total_length
```

Be sure to configure Velocity with `input.encoding = UTF-8`.

With Velocity 1.7+, you can call `size()` on an array as if it was a list (as well as `isEmpty()` and `get(int)`).

Comment: #set( $total_length = $data.getBytes('UTF-8').size())
$total_length   // Output is coming as 8
Need to get the output as 7

Comment: Yes, I tested this code. "9" means your input encoding is wrong.